# Attempting to read text of element shows text of first element only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fetching a list from a controller and displaying it in the view in tile format using ASP.Net MVC.

When I click on a particular tile it should display an `alert` message of the application name for that particular tile. However whichever tile I click I am getting the first application name for all the tiles. Please help.

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="cms-boxes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
          <div class="col-md-4 cms-boxes-outer">
            <div class="cms-boxes-items cms-features">
              <div class="boxes-align">
                <div class="small-box">
                  <h2 class="appnamedisplay">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApplicationName)</h2>
                  <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.number)</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".small-box").click(function() {
    var name = $(".appnamedisplay").html();
    alert(name);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting *all* the `.appnamedisplay` elements. Calling `html()` on that collection will only show you the value of the first element in that set.

To fix the issue, use DOM traversal to find the specific `.appnamedisplay` element which is related to the clicked `.small-box`. To do that use the `this` keyword to refer to the element which raised the event, and jQuery's `find()` method:

```
$(".small-box").click(function () {
  var name = $(this).find(".appnamedisplay").html();            
  console.log(name);
});
```

Also note the preferred use of `console.log()` to debug, as it doesn't block the UI from updating and also doesn't coerce data types as `alert()` does.